# How to get a file name into a code snippet in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, code-snippets

I am preparing a code snippet in Visual Studio 2019 Community.

I want one of parameters for my snippet was a file name, where I want the snippet to be inserted (let's call it a *"target file name"*).

If that is possible to get the file name as a replaceable parameter in the snippet, how do I do that?

By replaceable parameters I mean the ones with $some-parameter$ in the snippet.

Any ordinary parameter normally would be acquired from an `<Declaration>` section of the snippet. I am looking for a way to somehow fetch the *"target file file"* name from the view where I intend to put the snippet.

P.S. I did study the intro provided by the Microsoft [Walkthrough: Create a code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019) and hadn't find anything that could help here. I checked all the code snippets provided in Visual Studio too.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution. Did you find any?

Comment: @Artemious No, unfortunately I have not managed to find a way to automatically fetch the "target file name".I have used <ID> and <Default> sections of a <Literal> clause to simplify manual editing. Here is a description/sample featuring the approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019#replacement-parameters

Comment: thx. Anyway, in my case, it looks like the Item Templates feature would be the best choice to simplify the creation of a class.

Answer (score -1):

i find this solution and works, for me, i hope works for you: You can add `${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE}}` tag in json snippet file to get file name and add it to output of snippet.